# How to install a Python module via its setup.py in Windows?

Tags: python

I downloaded dateutil which comes with a setup.py file but it throws an error when I try to open it. What's the proper way to install this module?

This is the error:

```
 error: no commands supplied
```

Comment: You will need to provide the specific error message.

Comment: I can't tell -- the window closes too quickly

EDIT: looks like "error: no commands supplied"

Comment: You can't just double-click on it, you need to do this from the command line; try `python setup.py --help` to start with. :-)

Comment: Had to do python setup.py install -- thanks

Answer (score 144, accepted):

setup.py is designed to be run from the command line. You'll need to open your command prompt (In Windows 7, hold down shift while right-clicking in the directory with the setup.py file. You should be able to select "Open Command Window Here").

From the command line, you can type

```
python setup.py --help
```

...to get a list of commands. What you are looking to do is...

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: That is a very awesome trick (the Win7 shift shortcut), thanks!