# How to install packages listed in `install_requires` from setup.py without installing the main package?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way to install all of the packages that are listed in   `install_requires` of setup.py without installing the main package?

The list looks like:

```
    install_requires=[
                    'cassandra-driver==3.23.0',
                    # 'kafka-python==1.4.7',
                    # 'parmap==1.2.3',
                    'imblearn==0.0',
                    # 'imbalanced-learn==0.3.3',
                    'toolz==0.9.0',
                    ]
```

Is there any way to install directly from the setup file without having to separate the packages and use pip?

Comment: Does [How to install a Python module via its setup.py in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12324601/7010554) answer your question? The general idea, running `python setup.py install` from the command line, should also work on Linux.

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't want to install the package itself with `python setup.py install`? Because that installs the package *along with the items listed in `install_requires`*.

Comment: And what do you mean by "*without having to ... use pip*"?

Comment: @GinoMempin yes I dont want the package itself just it requirements
you're right i need to clarify I dont want to separate the packages and use pip like the answer below (the third suggestion)

Answer (score 1):

When looking at

```
pip install --help
```

you can see that you can either install all packages from the file itself with the help of

```
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

or you can do it in the command line like this:

```
pip install package1 package2 package3
```

Maybe have a look at the Pip-Documentary: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/

Comment: its not what i asked
my requirements are listed in the setup.py as a list:
    install_requires=[  # Infra
                        'cassandra-driver==3.23.0',
                        # 'kafka-python==1.4.7',
                        # 'parmap==1.2.3',
                        'imblearn==0.0',
                        # 'imbalanced-learn==0.3.3',
                        'toolz==0.9.0',
                        'prometheus_client==0.7.1',
]
i want to install them directly from the setup